# redirect user if the already logged in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to redirect logged in user if the comeback to my app the will redirected to home not to log in page.

in my login function like this

```
login(){
    this.googlePlus.login({
      'webClientId' : '927898787134-spvfdmvm9apq0e1fo2efvvura8vqpid8.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'offile' : true
    }).then(res=>{
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
      .then(suc=>{
        // console.log('users', JSON.stringify(suc));
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(suc));
        this.router.navigate(["/tabs/home"]);
      }).catch(ns=>{
        alert('Unsucessful');
      })
    })
  }
```

i have user data in my localStorage, i think i can check whether the user token is exist on localStorage or not. but when i try this in my login page

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (!user) {
        console.log("user is not logged in");
      } else {
        console.log("user is logged in");
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/home');
        return;
      }    
    });
  }
```

it doesn't redirected to home, did anyone know exactly how to do that?

after trying to insert to app.component.ts my code like this

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
      this.statusBar.show();
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (!user) {
          console.log("user is not logged in");
        } else {
          console.log("user is logged in");
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
          return;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

above code give me this error

[image: error]

heres my app-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'welcome', loadChildren: './welcome/welcome.module#WelcomePageModule' },
  { path: 'settings', loadChildren: './settings/settings.module#SettingsPageModule' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put it in `app.component.ts` after `constractor() { here your code }`

Comment: i edit my question, i add it to app.component.ts like so but i get Cannot read property 'navigateByUrl' of undefined on my console

Comment: You have problem in your router check the page name or use `this.router.navigate(['../home'])`

Comment: your function is working now because they find the user and they try to go to home but he can't check your router module, name of page, ../ or ./ according to your place of pages.

Comment: Change router to private : 
`constructor(private router: Router, ...)
 `

Comment: i am using private router: Router, but still get that error

Comment: can you post your router.module.ts

Comment: i dont have router.module.ts file

Comment: sorry app-routing.module.ts

Comment: I see there is no home page there, I think you need to create your home page again or to choose welcome page

Comment: do you mean add this { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' } ?

Comment: i re created my home page but still get the same error

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24805265)

Comment: try to change another page instead of home, or / and try to use `this.router.navigate(['../home'])  `

Comment: and please check that in your app-routing.module.ts you have 
`{
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
  },`

Comment: @dpr : this give solution for a part of question, if you check the changes of the question we will see that i resolve a part of the problem... 
I'm here to help as i can, i'm not looking for badges or reputation, if you want to delete my post i don't have any  problem. have a nice day.